# Analysis of Radix sort of $n$ $b$ bit numbers

Tags: sorting, radix-sort

I was reading radix sort in Introduction to Algorithms by CLRS . And it gave the following Lemma with its analysis 
[image]

I understood the proof of the Lemma but confused on the part where they try to minimize $\left( b / r\right) \left( n+2^{r}\right)$ .

While choosing $r$ the first case was $b < \left\lfloor \ln \right\rfloor$ . If we ignore the floor function we get $b < \ln \left( n\right)$.

Now how is this possible? Because when

$b < \ln \left( n\right) \\\Rightarrow 2^{b} < n\\\Rightarrow n>2^{b} $

But the maximum number of $b$ bit numbers are $2^{b}$ therefore $\max \left( n\right) =2^{b}$ this seems a contradiction .

Therefore $n\leq 2^{b}\\\Rightarrow \ln \left( n\right) \leq b $

Also following this it seems that $b=O\left( \ln \left( n\right) \right)$ doesn’t exactly seem right since we are getting $b\geq \ln \left( n\right)$

Can someone explain this ?

P.S. In this whole text and question $\ln \left( n\right)$ means $\log _{2}n$

Comment: Who said all numbers are distinct?

Comment: Ohh didn’t occur to me . Thx but is my argument right if the numbers are distinct ?

Comment: If the numbers are distinct, then $n \geq 2^b$. But they don't need to be distinct.